# Adding preceding zeros for a particular field based on value in that field in JCL

Tags: sorting, jcl

I have tried adding preceding zeros to a field in JCL
but all idea which I tried are not matching with my requirements.
my requirement is to add preceding zeros only if the field is numeric and
only if field is having preceding spaces.

**Input**
[Sample Input](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ctSXd.jpg)

> ```
> 123457 0 |  
> 34567R   |  
> 997654D3 |  
>     45833|  
> 23       |  
>    112456|  
>   56  64 |
> ```

**Expected Output:**
[Sample output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YTdHX.jpg)

> ```
> 123457 0 |  
> 34567R   |  
> 997654D3 |  
> 000045833|  
> 23       |  
> 000112456|  
>   56  64 |
> ```

I have already tried a few methods, but didn't meet my requirements.
I have viewed the query [Add zero padding to string in JCL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858763/add-zero-padding-to-string-in-jcl) but it's not applicable in my case.

Below are what I have tried

**Method 1**

```
//STEP0001 EXEC PGM=SORT                                       
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYMNAMES DD *                                                
ALPHA,C'A, ,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M,N,O,P,Q,R,S,T,U,V,W,X,Y,Z' 
//SORTIN   DD *                                                
123457 0                                                       
34567R                                                         
997654D3                                                       
    45833                                                      
23                                                             
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                         
//SYSIN    DD *                                                    
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                 
  INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(01,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,02,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,   
                      03,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,04,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,   
                      05,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,06,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,   
                      07,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,08,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,   
                      09,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA,OR,10,01,SS,EQ,ALPHA),     
  BUILD=(1,10)),                                                   
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=NONE,BUILD=(1,10,UFF,M11,LENGTH=10))                
//
```

**Method 2**

```
//STEP0001 EXEC PGM=SORT                                               
//SYSOUT   DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SORTIN   DD *                                                        
123457   0                                                             
34567                                                                  
997654                                                                 
4568 F ABC                                                             
23 1     1                                                             
//SORTOUT  DD SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSIN    DD *                                                        
  SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                     
  INREC IFOUTLEN=50,IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,OVERLAY=(51:1,10,TRAN=ALTSEQ)),  
  IFTHEN=(WHEN=(51,10,FS,EQ,NUM),OVERLAY=(1:1,10,UFF,M11,LENGTH=10))   
  ALTSEQ CODE=(40F0)                                                   
/*
```

**Method 3**

```
//STEP001  EXEC PGM=SORT                      
//SORTIN DD *                                 
764536 27                                     
0097865432                                    
00065499234                                   
00012342345                                   
12301231233                                   
//SORTOUT DD SYSOUT=*                         
//SYSIN DD *                                  
  OPTION COPY                                 
  INREC BUILD=(1,11,UFF,M11,LENGTH=11)        
//
```

**Note:**
- It will be better if we can do it in ICETOOL
- Other sort methords are also fine.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possible solution using SYNCSORT.  It may work with DFSORT as well.

Solution modified to check for values containing non-numeric characters or embedded blanks.

The example illustrates a numeric field contained within columns 1 - 5.

"Numeric" is assumed to mean digits 0 - 9 only.  Handling signs (+/-) or decimal points would obviously be more complicated.

Also, the large number of control statements required make this solution impractical for very long fields or large numbers of fields.

A much better option, if it is available to you, would be to write a sort exit routine to perform the data validation and zero-padding.

This solution works as follows:

The initial BUILD creates a temporary record containing:

cols 1 - 5 : the data field

cols 6 - 10 : a copy of the data field, which will be padded with leading zeroes

col 11 : a flag to indicate whether the data field is valid numeric (blank) or invalid ('I')

col 12 : a flag to keep track of the data field status, updated as each character is processed.  (blank) = all characters processed have been blank; ('N') = a non-blank character has been processed; ('B') = a trailing blank following a non-blank character has been processed.

For each character in the data field, there are five IFTHEN tests:

(1) If the character is neither a blank nor a numeric digit, the invalid flag (col 11) is set to 'I'.

(2) If the character is non-blank, and all characters previously processed have been blank, the status flag (col 12) is set to 'N'.

(3) If the character is blank, and a non-blank character has been processed, the status flag (col 12) is set to 'B'.

(4) If the character is non-blank, and a trailing blank character has been processed, the invalid flag (col 11) is set to 'I' (because the data field contains an embedded blank).

(5) If the character is non-blank, and all characters previously processed have been blank, the blank in the copy of the data (cols 6 - 10) is replaced with a zero.

After all characters have been processed:

If the field is either invalid numeric data, or blank, the output record is built using the original data (cols 1 - 5).

Otherwise, the output record is built using the data that has been padded with leading zeroes (cols 6 - 10).

```
//STEP1   EXEC PGM=SYNCSORT                                             
//SYSOUT   DD  SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SORTIN   DD  *                                                        
    1                                                                   
   1                                                                    
  1                                                                     
 1                                                                      
1                                                                       
   12                                                                   
  12                                                                    
 12                                                                     
12                                                                      
  123                                                                   
 123                                                                    
123                                                                     
 1234                                                                   
1234                                                                    
12345                                                                   

1 2                                                                     
 1 2                                                                    
  1 2                                                                   
1 23                                                                    
 1 23                                                                   
12 3                                                                    
 12 3                                                                   
    X                                                                   
   X                                                                    
  X                                                                     
 X                                                                      
X                                                                       
   1X                                                                   
  X1                                                                    
 1X                                                                     
1X                                                                      
  12X                                                                   
 12X                                                                    
1X3                                                                     
 12X4                                                                   
X234                                                                    
12X45                                                                   
/*                                                                      
//SORTOUT  DD  SYSOUT=*                                                 
//SYSIN    DD  *                                                        
 SORT FIELDS=COPY                                                       
 INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=INIT,                                               
       BUILD=(1,5,1,5,C'  ')),                                          
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,1,1,FS,NE,NUM),               
          OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                            
                   HIT=NEXT),                                           
           IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),           
            OVERLAY=(12:C'N'),                                          
                     HIT=NEXT),                                         
             IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'N'),         
              OVERLAY=(12:C'B'),                                        
                       HIT=NEXT),                                       
               IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),       
                OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                      
                         HIT=NEXT),                                     
                 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(1,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),     
                  OVERLAY=(6:C'0'),                                     
                           HIT=NEXT),                                   
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(2,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,2,1,FS,NE,NUM),               
          OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                            
                   HIT=NEXT),                                           
           IFTHEN=(WHEN=(2,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),           
            OVERLAY=(12:C'N'),                                          
                     HIT=NEXT),                                         
             IFTHEN=(WHEN=(2,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'N'),         
              OVERLAY=(12:C'B'),                                        
                       HIT=NEXT),                                       
               IFTHEN=(WHEN=(2,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),       
                OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                      
                         HIT=NEXT),                                     
                 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(2,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),     
                  OVERLAY=(7:C'0'),                                     
                           HIT=NEXT),                                   
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,3,1,FS,NE,NUM),               
          OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                            
                   HIT=NEXT),                                           
           IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),           
            OVERLAY=(12:C'N'),                                          
                     HIT=NEXT),                                         
             IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'N'),         
              OVERLAY=(12:C'B'),                                        
                       HIT=NEXT),                                       
               IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),       
                OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                      
                         HIT=NEXT),                                     
                 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(3,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),     
                  OVERLAY=(8:C'0'),                                     
                           HIT=NEXT),                                   
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,4,1,FS,NE,NUM),               
          OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                            
                   HIT=NEXT),                                           
           IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),           
            OVERLAY=(12:C'N'),                                          
                     HIT=NEXT),                                         
             IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'N'),         
              OVERLAY=(12:C'B'),                                        
                       HIT=NEXT),                                       
               IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),       
                OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                      
                         HIT=NEXT),                                     
                 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(4,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),     
                  OVERLAY=(9:C'0'),                                     
                           HIT=NEXT),                                   
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,5,1,FS,NE,NUM),               
          OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                            
                   HIT=NEXT),                                           
           IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),           
            OVERLAY=(12:C'N'),                                          
                     HIT=NEXT),                                         
             IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'N'),         
              OVERLAY=(12:C'B'),                                        
                       HIT=NEXT),                                       
               IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,1,CH,NE,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C'B'),       
                OVERLAY=(11:C'I'),                                      
                       HIT=NEXT),                                       
                 IFTHEN=(WHEN=(5,1,CH,EQ,C' ',AND,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),     
                  OVERLAY=(10:C'0'),                                    
                           HIT=NEXT),                                   
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(11,1,CH,EQ,C'I',OR,12,1,CH,EQ,C' '),             
          BUILD=(1,5)),                                                 
         IFTHEN=(WHEN=(11,1,CH,NE,C'I',AND,12,1,CH,NE,C' '),            
          BUILD=(6,5))                                                  
/*
```

Output:

```
00001
0001 
001  
01   
1    
00012
0012 
012  
12   
00123
0123 
123  
01234
1234 
12345

1 2  
 1 2 
  1 2
1 23 
 1 23
12 3 
 12 3
    X
   X 
  X  
 X   
X    
   1X
  X1 
 1X  
1X   
  12X
 12X 
1X3  
 12X4
X234 
12X45
```

Comment: how is checking that fields is numeric? I see you looking for spaces and replacing them with 0, but I don't see where you check if the input is numeric

Comment: You're right; I missed that requirement.  Solution updated.  Thanks!

Comment: Thank you guys for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution for the question using SORT.

```
OPTION COPY                                                         
INREC IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,12,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'000000000000')),
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,11,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'00000000000')), 
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,10,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'0000000000')),  
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,09,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'000000000')),   
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,08,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'00000000')),    
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,07,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'0000000')),     
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,06,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'000000')),      
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,05,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'00000')),       
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,04,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'0000')),        
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,03,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'000')),         
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,02,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'00')),          
      IFTHEN=(WHEN=(13,01,CH,EQ,C' '),OVERLAY=(13:C'0'))
```

Comment: but this doesn't check if the input is numeric which was a requirement of your original question

Comment: Yes, it is not validating whether numeric or not. But it works as per my expectation.

Comment: you should probably edit the question to remove that restriction.